# How to create dark background and/or monochrome version of logo?

Tags: color, logo

I was redoing a logo that I did before for a company.

Original Logo:
[image: Original Logo]

New Logo:
[image: New Logo]

Flat Version:
[image: Flat Version]

Dark-Background Version:
[image: Dark-Background Version]

As you can see the dark version is not of a single shade of grey, if I make it all white it loses the depth in the logo. Can someone guide me in how to make it a single color(shade), so that the depth is not lost?

Comment: Your dark background version IS monochrome. Monochrome means one color, not all the same shade of one color. If the goal is to print with one ink, then this works.

Comment: @Logarr Yeah, I'll edit my question a bit then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add black strokes to the problematic places. All other can now be white or other light color. If it must stand as well in all dark backgrounds other than black, cut slits instead of the black strokes. Be sure that the strokes or slits are wide enough to be seen as printed or onscreen apps.

[image]

ADDENDUM: There's also another possiblity:

[image]

The apparent bendings are different, but easily recognizable. Use this, if you like it.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a white stroke to each shape in the logo to separate these on the monochrome version. Play with the thickness of the stroke and covert it to outlines when you're done so it scales properly at different sizes.

If the shape is too complex for this to work, try stroking the [reduced version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfZVg.png) you showed us. It is good practice to simplify the shape for monochrome when the artwork is too busy.

[image]

Comment: I've converted my lines to shapes already and have lost those line strokes, can you guide me on how can I recover that in Illustrator? Also, I think the depth of the shapes is still lost.

Comment: I tried what you said it looks like this [link](http://imgur.com/a/6Knd1) and is not looking good due to the high number of strokes. It may look good on something like the diamond you showed. @Lucian

Comment: See my edit above.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. Also, I'd like to ask should the monochrome and dark bg version be the same? Or can they be different? Also should a logo have a reduced version or is a complex artwork logo enough?

Comment: Please answer if you can :) @Lucian

Comment: Nobody's going to tell you what these should and should not be. You are designing this so you are free to make these choices. There is no SHOULD here, but yes they COULD be the same, or different. You just need to play with these and think about their usage and come up with the best solution. We don't have the full briefing here to make these choices for you.